# How to find files from a folder in an app file Mac

Tags: python, macos, sockets, py2app

I have a .app file made with py2app which is supposed to show the contents of the folder on a localhost server but I realized that it only shows the files inside the .app and not the folder it's in, is there a way to make it so that it shows the files from the folder that it's in?
Here's my code:

```
import socketserver

PORT = 8080
Handler = http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

with socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler) as httpd:
    print("serving at port", PORT)
    httpd.serve_forever()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can modify the code to serve the files from the folder that the .app file is located in by specifying the directory path in the SimpleHTTPRequestHandler constructor.

You can use the os module to get the directory path of the current .app file and pass it to the SimpleHTTPRequestHandler constructor.

Here's an example code that should work for you:

```
import os
import http.server
import socketserver

PORT = 8080
Handler = http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

# Get the directory path of the current .app file
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

# Set the document root to the directory path
Handler.directory = dir_path
Handler.cgi_directories = []

with socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler) as httpd:
    print("serving at port", PORT)
    httpd.serve_forever()
```

Comment: Sorry but where should I put the directory path?

Comment: In this code, we use the os.path.dirname function to get the directory path of the current .app file and set it as the document root for the SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.